Problema para enviar email usando jobs en laravel 11
Estoy tratando de enviar correos usando jobs, un formulario con livewire y mailtrap, el problema que tengo es que no me llegan los correos, la configruación del envio parece funcionar correctamente en el backend, ademas se crear el registro en la tabla jobs y también en la tabla donde dejo un respaldo del correo, en ningun momento cae en failed_jobs como para ver el problema si existiera,luego de un momento, microsegundos o segundos desaparece de la tabla jobs y en la consola dejo corriendo php artisan queue:work y me arroja que la tarea fue ejecutada sin problema alguno, les comparto mi codigo a ver si hay algo que se me ha pasado o debo cambiar...
Ruta
Route::get('/send-emails', \App\Livewire\MarketingForm::class)
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])
    ->name('send-emails');

Luego su migracion
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('marketings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('asunto');
            $table->text('mensaje');
            $table->string('correos'); // Puede ser un string con correos separados por coma
            $table->string('adjunto')->nullable(); // Ruta del archivo adjunto
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('marketings');
    }
};

tambien el modelo
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Marketing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'asunto',
        'mensaje',
        'correos',
        'adjunto',
    ];
}

Luego tengo este Job
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\MarketingMail;
use App\Models\Marketing;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendMarketingEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $marketing;

    public function __construct(Marketing $marketing)
    {
        $this->marketing = $marketing;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        // Obtener la lista de correos
        $correos = explode(',', $this->marketing->correos);
        foreach ($correos as $correo) {
            Mail::to(trim($correo))->queue(new MarketingMail($this->marketing->asunto, $this->marketing->mensaje));
        }
    }
}


y tambien el el Mailable Mail
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MarketingMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $asunto;
    public $mensaje;
    public $adjunto;

    public function __construct($asunto, $mensaje, $adjunto = null)
    {
        $this->asunto = $asunto;
        $this->mensaje = $mensaje;
        $this->adjunto = $adjunto; // Ruta del archivo adjunto (si existe)
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: $this->asunto, // Se pasa el asunto dinámico
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            text: 'This is a test email to confirm the email delivery.', // Texto plano para probar
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        if ($this->adjunto) {
            return [
                Attachment::fromPath(storage_path('app/' . $this->adjunto)), // Ruta del adjunto
            ];
        }

        return [];
    }
}

y aca tengo mi Componente de Livewire
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Jobs\SendMarketingEmail;
use App\Models\Marketing;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class MarketingForm extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $asunto;
    public $mensaje;
    public $correos;
    public $adjunto;

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'asunto' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'mensaje' => 'required|string',
            'correos' => 'required|string',
            'adjunto' => 'nullable|file|mimes:pdf,jpg,png|max:2048', // Limita el tipo de archivo y tamaño
        ]);

        // Guardar en la base de datos
        $marketing = Marketing::create([
            'asunto' => $this->asunto,
            'mensaje' => $this->mensaje,
            'correos' => $this->correos,
            'adjunto' => $this->adjunto ? $this->adjunto->store('attachments') : null,
        ]);

        // Despachar el job para enviar el correo
        SendMarketingEmail::dispatch($marketing);

        // Reiniciar campos
        $this->reset();

        session()->flash('message', 'Correos enviados exitosamente.');
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.marketing-form');
    }
}

y finalmente la vista marketing-form
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
        <div>
            <label>Asunto</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="asunto" required>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Mensaje</label>
            <textarea wire:model="mensaje" required></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Correos a enviar</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="correos" required placeholder="ejemplo1@correo.com, ejemplo2@correo.com">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Adjunto</label>
            <input type="file" wire:model="adjunto">
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Enviar Correos</button>
    </form>

    @if (session()->has('message'))
        <div>{{ session('message') }}</div>
    @endif
</div>

y bueno ya luego corriendo el comando php artisan queue:work y me arroja como mensaje Running y luego Done, y como explique anteriormente pasa de la tabla jobs a ser enviado, fuera de esto no entiendo que problema puede haber entre medio porque en el log de laravel no me arroja error...
Obviamente en mi .env esta configurado asi
BROADCAST_CONNECTION=log
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

CACHE_STORE=database
CACHE_PREFIX=

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

# Looking to send emails in production? Check out our Email API/SMTP product!
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=theusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=thepassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL=stack

Basicamente para resumir el correo dice enviarse pero no llega al sandbox de mailtrap...
Actualizo mi post, resulta que hice pruebas en producción y en local como estoy trabajando con Docker los envios no me funcionan, pero al pasar unos cambios a producción, los envios si se realizan sin problemas, alguna sugerencia frente a esto?
Muchas gracias!

¿Y si pruebas de cambiar el MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS y poner un email que no tenga problemas de SPF/DKIM/DMARC y que sus registros de SPF/DKIM/DMARC se correspondan con la IP desde la cual estas mandando el correo?   Digo yo que aunque sea de pruebas ese servidor de mailtrap, algún filtro tendrá.  O quizás si lo recibe pero al reenviarlo a su destino (si es que eso funciona así) le peta por eso y no te enteras pues lo maneja el. (ni idea de como funciona mailtrap, pero pinta que el problema lo tienes alli)

Bueno el problema parece estar en local, en desarrollo usando docker, ya que hice pruebas con pasar a producción y me funciona perfecto el envio de email...

Mira a ver si llegas al mailtrap desde tu conexión local. Prueba escribiendo telnet sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io 2525.  Si no se conecta a nada y se queda pensando mucho rato es que tienes algun tipo de bloqueo en el router o en tu proveedor de internet local, o en tu propia máquina (firewall).

si llega bro, si hice eso mismo ayer y la conexion al menos desde mi pc la realiza, de alguna u otra forma algo me esta bloqueando la conexion, se me ocurre que es docker que le falta algo, porque al pasar a producción me funciona perfectamente!

Pues si es cosa del docker entonces deberás realizar tu pregunta en otra parte, pues aquí más bien tocamos programación, no containers ni SO, lo siento.  Lo comento porque según dices tu programación funciona bien fuera del docker. Supongo que el sitio más indicado ahora seria https://serverfault.com/. Suerte!

Tranquilo amigo, las he realizado en otra parte... El archivo de docker también hay que configurarlo, quizas ahi hay que agregar algo mas... en fin, Muchas gracias!

Usas sail o un docker-compose personalizado?

Sail amigo, la instalación la hago usando la documentación del mismo Laravel... Saludos!
